# how to represent choices in activity diagram?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

How can I draw activity diagram for following situation:-

Administrator logins to the system.

After login, there are 8 buttons on the screen for different works.

1. Add user

2. View users 

3. change login info

4. Group Task 

5. Settings

6. Reports

7. Home

8. Log Off

The admin can click on any button & will proceed with that work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a choice between one of the 8 buttons:

- This is modelled in UML activity diagrams with a [decision node](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-controls.html#decision-node)  represented with a losange having 8 outgoing edges.
- If the control flow reaches the decision node, only one branch will be chosen.
- Alternative paths can later be merged again with a merge node.

This shall not be confused with fork and join which create and synchronise parallel flows.

Answer (score -1):

This will be represented by "Fork/Union" which is typically a thick black horizontal bar. If you look at the Wikipedia article on activity diagrams here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram, you'll see

> "bars represent the start (split) or end (join) of concurrent activities"

In the example activity diagram they have provided - http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Activity_conducting.svg - you can see that the choice of either recording or presenting the idea is represented as two choices under the black horizontal bar.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, I think that indicates recording while presenting. Simultaneously (in parallel). There's no option. If I'm not mistaken.